# Transformation of the uppercase form of a number into type integer in R

Tags: r

In my dataset, i have variables, where numbers are written in uppercase format.
For example:

```
18 123 thousand dollars
19123 millon dollars
```

How using R to transform this format to type integer?
I mean, i need this format.

```
18 123 000
19 123 000 000
```

Comment: but 18 123 000 is 18 Million 123 thousands... How are you making logic of that?

Comment: yes, you are right, so this data comes from manager in this format! so "thousand dollar"  replace on "000"

Comment: the phrase "millon dollars" replace on "000 000"

Comment: is it just thousand and million or do you have others? If its only those two then just run `gsub` twice: `gsub("thousand dollars", "000", x)`

Comment: d.b , x is mydata$var?

Answer (score 1):

```
options(scipen=999)     //it will prevent long numbers conversion in scientific notation
df= data.frame(amount = c("18 123 thousand dollars","19 123 million dollars"))
df$amount <-  gsub("thousand dollars","000",df$amount)
df$amount <-  gsub("million dollars","000 000",df$amount)
df$amount <-  gsub("billion dollars","000 000 000",df$amount)
df$amount <-  gsub("\\s+","",df$amount)
df$amount <-  as.numeric(df$amount)
df
```